# C++, A* Search Program doesn't calculate distance from exit correctly

Tags: c++, a-star

I've been having issues with Visual Studio so apologizes in advance, but i've been using online sites to compile and can't use break points, as much as i'd love to on this program right now.

I'm still working on it, but right now getting the H values for A*Star, the distance from the exit, doesn't seem to display / calculate correctly.

It works up to a point, then it seems to start working backwards.

I believe the problem is in my search though that gives the nodes their value, and that it is displaying correctly but just not as expected. Point 110 onwards. EG:

```
int start = 0;
bool search = true;
aStarArray[myCoord.endY][myCoord.endX].h = 0; // End cell coord, written as 0 for the H array. (0 distance to exit)

while (search == true) // Will end as soon as all nodes have been valued. 
{
    for (myCoord.y = 0; myCoord.y < HEIGHT; ++myCoord.y)
    {
        for (myCoord.x = 0; myCoord.x < WIDTH; ++myCoord.x)
        {
            if (aStarArray[myCoord.y][myCoord.x].h == start) // Is value we're looking for.
            {
                if (myCoord.y + 1 <= HEIGHT)
                {
                    if (aStarArray[myCoord.y+1][myCoord.x].h == -1) // Not blocked, but not distanced yet and is a valid cell.
                    {
                        aStarArray[myCoord.y+1][myCoord.x].h = start + 1; // Then give it a value of parent cell + 1. (start + 1)
                        search = false;
                    }
                }

                if (myCoord.y - 1 >= 0)
                {
                    if (aStarArray[myCoord.y-1][myCoord.x].h == -1)
                    {
                        aStarArray[myCoord.y-1][myCoord.x].h = start + 1;
                        search = false;
                    }
                }

                if (myCoord.x + 1 <= WIDTH)
                {
                    if (aStarArray[myCoord.y][myCoord.x+1].h == -1)
                    {
                        aStarArray[myCoord.y][myCoord.x+1].h = start + 1;
                        search = false;
                    }
                }

                if (myCoord.x - 1 >= 0)
                {
                    if (aStarArray[myCoord.y][myCoord.x-1].h == -1)
                    {
                        aStarArray[myCoord.y][myCoord.x-1].h = start + 1;
                        search = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    start = start + 1;

    if (search == false) // A change was made to a node on this loop of the array.
    {
        search = true; // Then assume more nodes await values, keep searching.
                       // Now we're moving on to one of those new distanced cells, so the parent changes and thus search terms. 
                       // Start gets +1, so it's start searching for the new cells. And then it'll distance their neighbour cells to start+1, cycle repeats.
    }
    else // No changes.
    {
        search = false; // No need to search anymore, theoretically. 
    }
}
}
```

The outcome currently is this:

```
Get H values for every node
6  7  6  5  4
5  6  5  4  3
4  5  4  3  2
3  4  3  2  1
2  3  2  1  0
```

When I want it to be this, for example:

```
Get H values for every node
8  7  6  5  4
7  6  5  4  3
6  5  4  3  2
5  4  3  2  1
4  3  2  1  0
```

The full code can be found here:
cpp.sh/8iykn

If anyone has some advice to fix getting H it would be appreciated, or just any mistakes in general. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your code](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) ?

Comment: The fact that you can't debug on online compilers doesn't mean you don't still hold the responsibility of debugging before you post. We are not a free, crowdsourced debugger. We are not here to do your debugging for you for free. Find a way around your constraints so that you can debug your code. Visual Studio may be obtained for free.

Comment: I have to the best I can.
I've spent several hours and tried multiple different implementations but none has come as close to this one. 

The only warnings I have are two unused parameters, but I know why this is and it's not the problem. 

And as explained, i'd like to use breakpoints but can't, and that'd be only other thing i'd have done otherwise. 

This is my last resort, as chances are it's something I don't understand so it's pointless for me to keep going over it as i'm assuming something to be correct that isn't.

Comment: BTW, heuristic computation is not true distance but fast lower-bound estimation.

Comment: It looks like your heuristic is manhattan distance? Why not just use `abs(x-exit.x)+abs(y-exit.y)` for each position?

Comment: @Kevin It's manhattan, yeah. I'm unfamiliar with the usage of abs unfortunately, it's not something i've covered yet in my course. I've only learnt about it through browsing StackOverflow and subsequently cplusplus.com.


I'll need to ask my tutor about it after the holidays since it seems so popular. If I finish my program soon, I might try it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check

```
if (myCoord.y + 1 <= HEIGHT)
```

is wrong. It should be

```
if (myCoord.y + 1 < HEIGHT)
```

Same for `WIDTH`